# The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly. System.Exception: Unit test Provider already set

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, specflow

I have installed some specflow packages in .NET Core 3.1

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="16.11.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation" Version="3.9.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecFlow.xUnit" Version="3.9.22" />
    <PackageReference Include="SpecRun.SpecFlow" Version="3.9.7" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Hooks\" />
  </ItemGroup>    

</Project>
```

But when I build, I got this error:

[image]

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   MSB4018 The "GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Unit test Provider already set.
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.UnitTestProviderConfiguration.UseUnitTestProvider(String unitTestProviderName)
   at TechTalk.SpecFlow.xUnit.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.GeneratorPlugin.Initialize(GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, GeneratorPluginParameters generatorPluginParameters, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration) in D:\a\1\s\Plugins\TechTalk.SpecFlow.xUnit.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin\GeneratorPlugin.cs:line 14
```

Answer (score 0):

SpecRun.SpecFlow and SpecFlow.NUnit can't be installed at the same time in a SpecFlow project. They are used to configure which unit test runner is used.

I assume that you had SpecFlow+ Runner selected, when creating the SpecFlow project. This adds the SpecRun.SpecFlow NuGet package.

And as you add then manually the SpecFlow.NUnit package, you are getting this error.
You can select NUnit in the project wizard, to get from the start a project with NUnit.

This behavior has existed since SpecFlow 3.0.

Docs for Unit Test Provider: https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/Installation/Unit-Test-Providers.html