# GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask task failed unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, specflow

when I try to build I am getting this error.

I am using VS studio 2019, and Specflow 3.9.69

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error The

"GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask" task failed unexpectedly.
System.Exception: Unit test Provider already set.
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.UnitTestProvider.UnitTestProviderConfiguration.UseUnitTestProvider(String unitTestProviderName)
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.MSTest.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin.GeneratorPlugin.Initialize(GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, GeneratorPluginParameters generatorPluginParameters, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration) in D:\a\1\s\Plugins\TechTalk.SpecFlow.MSTest.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin\GeneratorPlugin.cs:line 14
at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.LoadPlugins(ObjectContainer container, GeneratorPluginEvents generatorPluginEvents, UnitTestProviderConfiguration unitTestProviderConfiguration, IEnumerable`1 generatorPlugins) at TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator.GeneratorContainerBuilder.CreateContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder configurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IEnumerable`1 generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer parentObjectContainer)
at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.WrappedGeneratorContainerBuilder.BuildGeneratorContainer(SpecFlowConfigurationHolder specFlowConfigurationHolder, ProjectSettings projectSettings, IReadOnlyCollection`1 generatorPluginInfos, IObjectContainer rootObjectContainer)
at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTaskExecutor.Execute()
at SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation.GenerateFeatureFileCodeBehindTask.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() SchuhTestProject

Comment: Simply googling the error yielded [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69171035/the-generatefeaturefilecodebehindtask-task-failed-unexpectedly-system-excepti)

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one of these NuGet packages added to your project:

- SpecFlow.xUnit
- SpecFlow.MSTest
- SpecFlow.NUnit

Remove the one that you don't want.

You can only have one of these, as they configure SpecFlow which Test Runner it should use.